# PayPal ipn unsolicited refund or reversal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

As a merchant, can PayPal ever send me a `payment_status = Refund | Reversal` without any action on my part? Or are they only ever sent after an instruction from the merchant to refund?

It's a bit confusing, because the IPN example code specifically tells you to only handle "completed" transactions, but if these reversals are unsolicited it seems like you could end up with a situation where someone pays, then reverses the payment and you don't detect it.

I already checked the docs and couldn't find an answer:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/
https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/ipnguide.pdf

Answer (score 1):

PayPal will reverse a transaction when a case is opened. The funds are then frozen at PayPal. When the case closes, either you lose and the funds go back to the purchaser, or you win and the funds are returned to you via a reversal-reversal, whose name I forget, sorry, possibly a reversal-cancelled.

Comment: The name @user207421 is trying to remember sounds like PayPal's `Canceled-Reversal`, defined as:

_"`Canceled-Reversal` — A reversal has been canceled, for example, when you win a dispute and the funds for the reversal have been returned to you."_

It is mentioned in the GetTransactionDetails NVP API docs for the `PAYMENTSTATUS` field at https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/get-transaction-details-nvp/